# How to map a C union with const char* to C# struct?

Tags: c#, c++, c, interop, callback

In a callback function from a native library, I need to access an array of espeak_EVENT.
The problem is the UNION statement in the original C code:

```
typedef struct {
    espeak_EVENT_TYPE type;
    unsigned int unique_identifier; // message identifier (or 0 for key or character)
    int text_position;    // the number of characters from the start of the text
    int length;           // word length, in characters (for espeakEVENT_WORD)
    int audio_position;   // the time in mS within the generated speech output data
    int sample;           // sample id (internal use)
    void* user_data;      // pointer supplied by the calling program
    union {
        int number;        // used for WORD and SENTENCE events. For PHONEME events this is the phoneme mnemonic.
        const char *name;  // used for MARK and PLAY events.  UTF8 string
    } id;
} espeak_EVENT;
```

I have

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
        public struct espeak_EVENT
        {
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(0)]
            public espeak_EVENT_TYPE type;

            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(4)]
            public uint unique_identifier;  // message identifier (or 0 for key or character)

            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(8)]
            public int text_position;    // the number of characters from the start of the text

            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(12)]
            public int length;           // word length, in characters (for espeakEVENT_WORD)

            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(16)]
            public int audio_position;   // the time in mS within the generated speech output data

            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(20)]
            public int sample;           // sample id (internal use)

            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(24)]
            public IntPtr user_data;      // pointer supplied by the calling program

            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(32)]
            public int number;

            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(32)]
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public string name; 
        }
```

And then

```
public static Int32 SynthCallback(IntPtr wav, Int32 numsamples, IntPtr eventsParameter)
        {
            if (wav == IntPtr.Zero) 
                return 0;

            int j=0;
            while(true)
            {
                System.IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr( 
                                                (
                                                    eventsParameter.ToInt64() 
                                                    + (j *
                                                        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(cEspeak.espeak_EVENT))
                                                      ) 
                                                )
                                              );
                if(ptr == IntPtr.Zero)
                    Console.WriteLine("NULL");

                cEspeak.espeak_EVENT events = (cEspeak.espeak_EVENT) System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(cEspeak.espeak_EVENT));

                if(events.type == cEspeak.espeak_EVENT_TYPE.espeakEVENT_SAMPLERATE)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Heureka");
                }
                break;


                //Console.WriteLine("\t\t header {0}: address={1}: offset={2}\n", j, info.dlpi_phdr, hdr.p_offset);
                ++j;
            }


            if(numsamples > 0)
            {
                byte[] wavbytes = new Byte[numsamples * 2];
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(wav, wavbytes, 0, numsamples*2);
                bw.Write(wavbytes, 0, numsamples*2);
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

But it always fails on

```
cEspeak.espeak_EVENT events = (cEspeak.espeak_EVENT) System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(cEspeak.espeak_EVENT));
```

However, when I remove

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(32)][System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public string name;
```

From espeak_event, then it works.

How can I make this work without removing the string in the union ?
I need to access it in the callback function.

**Edit:**
And btw, what happens to the field offsets if I let it run on x64, and the size of " public IntPtr user_data;" changes from 32 to 64 bit ?

Hm, thinking about it, is fieldoffset 32 correct ?
Seems I mixed-up the pointer size when thinking about x64.
That might very well be another bug.

Hm, union with int and char*, my guess is they never compiled it for x64.
Because sizof(int) is 32 bit on a x64 Linux system.

Comment: You probably can't because doing the marshal in a single call will automatically convert all fields, and you'll get an error when you convert a field that should be an integer not a pointer. Can you marshal after you check what type it is, using two different types?

Comment: @tinman: That was my thought, too, in the meantime. I could, by declaring the union field as intptr. That would work for x32, x64 however... 64/8 = 8 bytes = != int32

Comment: Using an IntPtr will work for both because the union in espeak would end up 8 bytes to be able to store the pointer when recompiled for 64 bit. PS, offset of 32 looks wrong, if the offset for user_data is correct at 24 then the next field would be at 28.

Comment: @tinman: Thanks, so I take into consideration, that all union members can be smaller or equal than it's largest member.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare `name` as `IntPtr` rather than `string` and then use `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi` to get it into a string variable.

I'm ignoring the fact that the string contents are UTF-8. If your text is pure ASCII that's fine. If not then you need to copy to a `byte[]` array and then translate from UTF-8 with `Encoding.UTF8.GetString`.

Comment: In the meantime, this was my thought too. Converting the string is not a problem. But then, how do I get the CONTENT of the int ? ptr.ToInt32() ?

Comment: @Quandary Exactly right. I just wouldn't bother with the FieldOffset stuff since you can get the integer out of an IntPtr too.

Comment: Of course, if you were working with a big endian machines then you would have to do a bit of extra work to get a 32 bit int out of the 64 bit IntPtr, but little endian works in your favour here.

Comment: Right, if I don't have the union anymore, I can scrap those annoying offsets.

Answer (score 0):

Now this might sound overly work intensive, but whenever I'm a situation where I must access through a binding some C structure utilizing C specific features (like unions or `void*` pointers), I normally write a set of get/set functions from/to the target language native (marshalling) types in C and provide those through the binding and keep the structure itself opaque.

Answer (score 0):

Can you first marshal a struct with only `espeak_EVENT_TYPE type`?  Then you could choose one of two structs depending on what you expect to find in the contents of the union:  one having only `int number` and one having only `const char *name`.